# How to proof the randomness of a number sequence?

Tags: functions, random

I've got a sequence of numbers generator by a "random number generator". Is there a way or a method to proof the randomness of the generator?

How would I even compare randomness of generators?

Or might it  be better to proof that a sequence is not random?

Comment: [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests) should give you some ideas, to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several random number tests, but it is impossible to prove that a sequence of numbers is in fact random.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to say something about the distribution of the generated sequence?

Comment: The easiest test is the test of equidistribution.

Comment: i.e. if it fails any of the tests, that shows that it is not random.  If it passes all the tests, it's a pretty good (pseudo-)random sequence

Comment: The concept of randomness is necessarily somewhat cloudy. And the tolerance how far distributions are allowed to differ from the theoretical ones, is quite subjective. Mostly, a probability error is fixed (lets say 1%) and if the probability for the observed deviations is less, the sequence is considered to fail the test.

Comment: The most popular test is the chi-squared-test.

Answer (score 2):

[The article by A. Kolmogorov and V. Uspenskii](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1132060) is a serious treatment of the topic.